# How do I do a button click background color change?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have read a lot of threads about this, but I cannot seem to get XamarinForms to do what I want it to do. I would like a button to briefly change its background color when clicked and then change it back again before processing the specific clicked function. Like, blue button changes to red for 200 ms and then changes back to blue and then the actual event processing happens.
I have created a BaseButton class that does the color change in its click response:

```
public class BaseButton : Button
{
    public BaseButton()
    {
        Clicked += (sender,e) =>
        {
            BackgroundColor = BaseColors.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor;
            TextColor = BaseColors.ButtonPressedTextColor;
            BorderColor = BaseColors.ButtonPressedBorderColor;
            this.ScaleTo(1,200);

            BackgroundColor = BaseColors.ButtonBackgroundColor;
            TextColor = BaseColors.ButtonTextColor;
            BorderColor = BaseColors.ButtonBorderColor;
            this.ScaleTo(1,200);
        };              
    }
}
```

This works great as long as there is no processing to do.
But, when I make BaseButton MyButton and say MyButton.Clicked += DoSomething, and have:

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessTheClick();    
}
```

When I click MyButton, there is a total delay of 400 ms after which both color changes happen with no delays, and ProcessTheClick() immediately executes.

It is as if the color changing has to wait for control to be released back to the UI.

How do I make the two color changes each followed by their respective delays before executing ProcessTheClick()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `async` and `await` to wait for the (color-changing) task to finish before proceeding to the tasks that you want to do afterwards.

Your `BaseButton` class should be:

```
public class BaseButton : Button
{
    public BaseButton()
    {
        Clicked += async (sender,e) =>
        {
            BackgroundColor = BaseColors.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor;
            TextColor = BaseColors.ButtonPressedTextColor;
            BorderColor = BaseColors.ButtonPressedBorderColor;
            await Task.Delay(200); // wait for 200ms

            BackgroundColor = BaseColors.ButtonBackgroundColor;
            TextColor = BaseColors.ButtonTextColor;
            BorderColor = BaseColors.ButtonBorderColor;
            await Task.Delay(200); // wait for 200ms

            // process the click after the 400ms total waiting
            ProcessTheClick();
        };              
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS!  This worked fine. I just had to make ProcessTheClick an EventHandler in order to say MyButton.ProcessTheClick += SomeFunction;